# Why do my .wav sound effects delay before playing the first time on iOS?

Tags: unity

First off, I'm using Unity 5.2.3. I have a bunch of .wav sounds that I play like this:

```
     Debug.Log(m_audioAssets.m_soundBanks[(int)m_currentSoundBank].m_multiplier[data].loadState);
     m_multiplierSource.clip = m_audioAssets.m_soundBanks[(int)m_currentSoundBank].m_multiplier[data];
     m_multiplierSource.Play();
```

The Debug.Log is just there temporarily, to verify that the sounds' loadState is "loaded". It is, every time they play. But the first time they play on my iPhone, there is a noticable delay before they start. After playing the first time, they work fine.

What am I supposed to do to get these sounds to preload properly? I have their "Preload Audio Data" boxes checked in the import settings, and they're set to "Decompress on Load".

Comment: Few suggestions,

- Try to decrease sound quality.
- Load all the sounds in audio source(s) at very first sight such as splash screen

Comment: But if I debug.log(soundclip.loadState) before playing it, it says "loaded". And after playing it once, it's fine. So I'm not sure what you mean "load them" if the engine already thinks they're loaded. If they play fine after the first time, I'm not sure what decreasing the sound quality will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not the sound. It was the score `Text` object updating, which has a problem on iOS if your font is set to Dynamic. Lesson: always check the profiler before trying to fix performance issues.

The big spike in the image is the first call to changing the score, and you can see that `Font.CacheFontForText` takes a long time.

[image]